# Problems with catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having problems with each time that I try to run catkin_make.  Here is a copy of what I get:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package cmake_modules.

  Set cmake_modules_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for cmake_modules.  The file will have one of the following names:

    cmake_modulesConfig.cmake
    cmake_modules-config.cmake
```

I have tried looking for the `cmake_modules_DIR`, but so far no luck.

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218107/problems-with-catkin_make/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2015-09-23**:
I am using hydro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro/indigo/jade-cmake-modules
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2015-09-23**:
When I run the command, I get: Unable to locate package ros-hydro/indigo.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-09-23**:
You need to put in your ROS version only.

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2015-09-23**:
In your case is

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-cmake-modules
```

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2015-09-24**:
I still get the same CMake Error: Could not find a configuration file for package cmake_modules.

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2015-09-24**:
I found the problem, I had a package that was causing the problem.  I removed the package, and now catkin_make works fine.  Thanks to all for your help.

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-04-19**:
Hi, which package did you remove to fix the issue? I have the same problem.

**Comment by [klindgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/28910/klindgren/) on 2019-06-24**:
On kinetic, Mago Nick's comment worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-cmake-modules
```